# Why is Haskell [] (list) not a type class?

Tags: list, haskell, types, interface, typeclass

I am writing a Haskell function which takes a list as input. That is, there's no reason it couldn't be a queue or dequeue, or anything that allows me to access its "head" and its "tail" (and check if it's empty). So the [a] input type seems too specific. But AFAIK there's no standard library typeclass that captures exactly this interface. Sure, I could wrap my function in a Data.Foldable.toList and make it polymorphic wrt Foldable, but that doesn't quite seem right (idiomatic).

Why is there no standard list type class? (And why is the "container" type class hierarchy in Haskell less developed than I think it should be?) Or am I missing something essential?

Comment: History, and also laziness makes it less necessary.  For example, `toList` essentially gives you an iterator because it's a lazy list.

Comment: I think it's tricky to identify the "correct" interface that captures a wide enough notion of "what you can do with a list" that you can actually implement reasonable algorithms with it generically, while still allowing reasonable implementations that aren't structurally similar to the native `[]`. Operating by consing and deconsing individual elements at the head is hugely inefficient for array-like structures, for example. That said, there are things like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike

Comment: Why does defining your function to take a `Foldable t => t a` argument seem wrong?

Comment: @chepner, there's nothing wrong about it, I guess, but it'd just be a wrapper that calls the original function with toList of the argument. It's not like Foldable has functions head/tail/isEmpty, which is what I would find more intuitive.

Comment: @Ben "tricky to identify the "correct" interface." Sure, but isn't that language-independent trickiness? That's why you would have a list at the top of the hierarchy, and then, say, FIFO queues and priority queues under that, then dequeues further down, etc.

Comment: I still don't quite see the kind of answers I was hoping for. I was hoping for something like "(In the absence of ViewPatterns), head and tail wouldn't let us pattern match on lists, and pattern matching is neat"

Comment: Initiality is a powerful form of abstraction.

Answer (score 13):

A given algebraic datatype can be represented as its catamorphism, a transformation known as [*Church encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding). That means lists are isomorphic to their `foldr`:

```
type List a = forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b

fromList :: [a] -> List a
fromList xs = \f z -> foldr f z xs

toList :: List a -> [a]
toList l = l (:) []
```

But `foldr` also characterises `Foldable`. You can define `foldMap` in terms of `foldr`, and vice versa.

```
foldMap f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t) z
```

(It shouldn't be surprising that `foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m` characterises lists, because lists are a free monoid.) In other words, `Foldable` basically gives you `toList` as a class. Instances of `Foldable` have a "path" through them which can be walked to give you a list; `Foldable` types have at least as much structure as lists.

---

Regarding your misgivings:

> It's not like `Foldable` has functions `head`/`tail`/`isEmpty`, which is what I would find more intuitive.

[`null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:null) is your `isEmpty`, and you can define (a safe version of) `head` straightforwardly with [an appropriate choice of `Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First):

```
head :: Foldable t :: t a -> Maybe a
head = getFirst . foldMap (First . Just)
```

`tail` is kinda tricky in my opinion. It's not obvious what `tail` would even mean for an arbitrary type. You can certainly write `tail :: Foldable t => t a -> Maybe [a]` (by `toList`ing and then unconsing), but I think any type `T` for which `tail :: T a -> Maybe (T a)` is defined would necessarily be structurally similar to lists (eg [`Seq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq)). Besides, in my experience, the vast majority of cases where you'd think you need access to a list's `tail` turn out to be folds after all.

That said, abstracting over unconsable types is occasionally useful. [`megaparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.3.0), for example, defines a [`Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-5.3.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#t:Stream) class for (monomorphic) streams of tokens to be used as input for a parser.

Comment: Thanks. Right. Of course, I could even define my own type class hierarchy and make instances for [], Dequeue etc. So it's more a question of why this doesn't seem to be common practice, and why there aren't standard type classes like this.

Comment: Very well motivated! This is truly an exceptional answer.

Comment: Ignoring Maybe, tail should satisfy "head x : toList (tail x) = toList x". For lists, that would be the usual tail. For balanced trees, it would be the re-balanced tree after removing the leftmost element.... "It's not obvious what tail would even mean for an arbitrary type". That's up to the designer of the type to decide, as long as the laws are satisfied, right? It's not obvious what mappend means for Num, that's why we have Sum and Product...

Answer (score 5):

**The Question**

Making your question more concrete, let's ask:

Why isn't the type class

```
class HasHeadAndTail t where
    head :: t a -> Maybe a
    tail :: t a -> Maybe (t a)
    isEmpty :: t a -> Bool
```

in the `base` library?

**An Answer**

This class is only useful for ordered, linear containers.  `Map`, `Set`, `HashMap`, `HashTable`, and `Tree` all would not be instances.  I'd even argue against making `Seq` and `DList` an instance since there are really two possible "heads" of that structure.

Also what can we say about any type that is an instance of this class?  I think the only property is if `isEmpty` is False then `head` and `tail` should be non-`Nothing`.  As a result, isEmpty shouldn't even be in the class and instead be a function `isEmpty :: HashHeadAndTail t => t a -> Bool ; isEmpty = isNothing . head`.

So my answer is:

- This class lacks utility in so far as it lacks instances.
- This class lacks useful properties and classes that lack properties are frequently discouraged.

Comment: The class is useful for 1. lists, 2. FIFO queues, 3. priority queues... The class could also be useful for trees, although the tail might need some rebalancing of the original tree (that would in fact be an obvious implementation option of a priority queue). "As a result, isEmpty shouldn't even be in the class". Huh? Why can't we have a convenience function with a default implementation? Eq has both == and /=.

Comment: [`IsSequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.1.3/docs/Data-Sequences.html#t:IsSequence) is a souped up version of `HasHeadAndTail`. I'm not a fan of it, but, for those who dislike qualified imports of, it _does_ present a sequence-like abstraction.

Comment: Despite FIFO and other types, I maintain the utility gap exislts.  Moving `isEmpty` back into the class is unnecessary and thus doesn't help the class become more principled - an optional isEmpty can't make head or tail optional and doesn't cause fundamental change.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson "principled". You don't think Haskell needs default implementations at all? So Monad doesn't need mconcat, then?